# New register email notification sending some fields blank on site admin emai id

Tags: user-registration, notifications, groupby

Working on real estate project.Here i am facing a problem with new email registration when user register with site admin getting some fields blank.i am using Group but plugin and also in back end under Group Buying Plugin > Account tab getting warning to city ,state colum like:

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'city' in /home/reddvise/public_html/app/wp-content/plugins/group-buying/controllers/groupBuyingAccounts.class.php on line 299.
```

I am using word press version 3.4.1 with Group buying plugin Version 3.5.1

**Getting Email like below example:-**
New user registration on your site Reddvise Real Estate:

User Id: 243
Username: sanjay

E-mail: sanjaynakate@gmail.com

Mobile No. :

Address :

City :

State :

Pin Code :

Country :

```
public static function column_display( $column_name, $id ) {
        global $post;
        $account = Group_Buying_Account::get_instance_by_id($id);

        if ( !$account ) 
            return; // return for that temp post

        $user = Group_Buying_Account::get_user_id_for_account($account->get_ID());
        $user_data = get_userdata($user);
        $address = $account->get_address();
        switch ( $column_name ) {
            case 'id':
                echo $id;
                break;

            case 'username':
                echo get_avatar( $user_data->user_email, '35' );
                $get_name = $account->get_name();
                $name = ( strlen($get_name) <= 1  ) ? $post->post_title : $get_name;
                echo '<strong><a href="'.get_edit_post_link().'">'.$name.'</a></strong><br/>';
                break;

            case 'user':
                echo '<a href="'.admin_url("user-edit.php?user_id=".$user).'">'.$user_data->user_login.'</a>';
                break;

            case 'state':
                echo $address['zone'];

                break;

            case 'city': //on this line getting a warning 
                echo $address['city'];
                break;

            default:
                # code...
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Also, try escaping the brackets.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12559121/php-variable-string-concatenation

Comment: I would ***STRONGLY*** advise you upgrade from v3.4.1, that version is years out of date and any answer your get will be assuming the current latest version ( v3.9.1 ). You're also missing a lot of information, such as what these plugins are, and the rest of your code

Comment: but the plugin is not showing any update

Comment: @TomJNowell you are right i have updated wp with latet version every thing working fine .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated wordpress 3.4.1 to wordpress 3.9.1 also i have updated all plugin version now code is working without any warning and error.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a variable for the parameter

```
user-edit.php?user_id=".$user
```

And pass that through `admin_url` function.

Comment: can you  elaborate it

Comment: I've had trouble before when mixing double quotes inside a parameter especially when using single quotes else where.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're getting that warning because `$address['city']` is obviously not set. In that case, PHP does not produce an error, instead it lets you get away with it with a `null` value and a warning.

If you just want to get rid of the warning, do something like:

```
        case 'city': //on this line getting a warning 
            echo isset($address['city'])?$address['city']:"(unknown)";
            break;
```

But if you want to further investigate things, do a `var_dump` after `$address` is given value:

```
    $address = $account->get_address();
    var_dump($address);
```

This way, you'll get a hint as to why `$account->get_address()` fails to deliver whatever it is you are expecting.